# Bootstrap 3 modal with input issues on Mobile Safari

Tags: ios, input, scroll, bootstrap-modal

I’m using Bootstrap 3 modal with input form. I’m try to solve the problem with update fixed position inputs on iOS (Mobile Safari). One of workarounds to set absolute position for modal.  I found this script and tried to launch.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var isiPhone = /iPhone/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
    if(isiPhone) {
    $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $(this)
            .css({
            position: 'absolute',
            marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 'px',
            bottom: 'auto',
            top:'auto'
            });

    setTimeout( function() {
        $('.modal-backdrop').css({
            position: 'absolute', 
            top: 0, 
            left: 0,
            width: '100%',
            height: Math.max(
            document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
            document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
            document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
            ) + 'px'
        });
    }, 500);

    var currentscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('input').on('blur', function() {
                if (!event.relatedTarget) {
                $(window).scrollTop(currentscroll);
                }
        });
 });}})
```

It’s work fine. When modal opens - position changes to absolute. Focus on inputs works correctly too. But I have long document and when modal opens, there is extra space before and after modal. Modal scrolls with body and it’s not good. I see three variants of solution but I don’t know how to make it:

1. To prevent modal with absolute position to scroll until input form not in focus.
2. To limit modal scrolling in small range to avoid long scroll when document is long.
3. To change position from fixed to absolute when input in focus and back when input in blur.

Thanks for any Help.